# how do I change an image on a certain date or a season

Tags: html, image, date

I help my wife and mother in law with their stores website. I have my own full time job. now my problem is I cant be online all time changing pictures for their website. my question is(and I don't know where to begin) can i change pictures on a website to other pictures within a folder withoout specifying what picture to change to. unless its a season picture I would like to change to.

I have two things first page has three categories that I can rotate through different images. Then I would like to change to different holidays with different pictures accordingly. I could have different folders for each and have pictures in each and cycle thru them. Any suggestions on tags? I'm sorry. I'm fairly new to this.

I have to wait till i'm really tired till my brain knows what I want. So thhe website is a jewelry store.

I have three grid with thumbnails.

first one is a ring. so i could make a folder and randomly pick a file within the ring folder.

and so on for the other two.

but my slide show I would like to change a picture with the holidays. valentines, chirstmas, etc. so this is what i'm wondering if I can select a specific day and then it would change the picture.

so as i'm typing i think its coming to me. I would have to do an array (like aditya prakash was saying) with an event for a specific day retrieve this file.

does that sound like it is possible? kind of like how you can send a text in the future. or automated message system.

Comment: Like using a generic name for the picture, like header.jpg, and copying the wanted picture over it when a change is needed? + note that there are likely better tags to get people to see your question...

Comment: Are you using any server side technology or is this just flat HTML?

Comment: I am using flat html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way. here i used array for specific image. the array has date and url if today date is in the array the image change to our array url value.

```js
let img_ring_images = [
  {
    date: "2019-10-03",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
  },
    {
    date: "2019-10-04",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
  },
    {
    date: "2019-10-05",
    url: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
  }
];

//get today date & format to YYYY-MM-DD
var today = new Date();
today = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];

//check today date in ring image array
object = img_ring_images.find(o => Object.entries(o).find(([k, value]) => k === 'date' && value === today) !== undefined);

//if today date in array change image url
if(object != null){

  $("#ring_image").attr("src",object.url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="ring_image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/607d8b/ffffff%20?Text=default%20img"/>
```

Comment: in the html code you are calling a src but in the javascript you are calling a src as well do you need both?

Comment: yeah, add the default image in the html, if you want to change image on specific date add the url & date in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with all the urls of the images you want to use. e.g.
HTML:

```
<img id="placeholder">
```

JS:

```
var imageUrls = [ 'http://placeholderURL/A', 
    'http://placeholderURL/B', // ... more 
    'http://placeholderURL/Z' ];
```

Then:

```
var img = document.getElementById('placeholder'); 
img.addEventListener("click", function() { this.src = imageUrls[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageUrls.length)]; });
```